# Laravel Upload with dropzone

Tags: php, laravel

I got simple/silly issue while uploading multiple photos with dropzone, I have seen many tutorial like this http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/howto-ajax-multiple-file-upload-in-laravel/ .

It always insert this code while uploading :

```
$extension = File::extension($file['name']);
```

but i get an error for : **Class 'App\Http\Controllers\File' not found**
and i dont know where to find that class

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It's because laravel can't find reference to the `File` class.

You can simply fix this issue by referencing the `File` class using:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
```

on the top of your controller class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply

```
 $extension = \File::extension($file['name']);
```